# Ng file upload - sending email with multiple attachments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, ng-file-upload

I'm new with ng-file-upload, which I used to send email with attachment. I'm wondering if I can send multiple files in one request with email.

I've found some stuff about ng file, that it is not supported. So can't get any good clue for this situation. It works perfectly with one file, but how it's with multiple?

Answer (score 1):

you can find here an example with multiple file selection and upload

```
<button ngf-select="uploadFiles($files)" multiple 
        accept="image/*">Select Files</button>
<br>
<br>Files:
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="f in files" style="font:smaller">
        {{f.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/huhjo9jm/5/

Comment: So, I understand that upload with FILES and EMAILDATA will be like:   Upload.upload({
                url: 'somewhere',
                data: {
                    files: files,
emailData: $scope.emailData

                }

Answer (score 0):

Finally problem is solved.

That was of course error on the backend side. All we have to do is change from MultipartFile to MultipartFile[] in controller, and then in my emailSender class add *for*:

```
 if (file != null) {
            for(MultipartFile fileOne : file) {
                String attachName = fileOne.getOriginalFilename();
                 helper.addAttachment(attachName, new InputStreamSource() {
                     @Override
                     public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                         return fileOne.getInputStream();
                     }
                 });
             }
        }
```